# Error in Selenium testcases while running

Tags: selenium

Using Selenium IDE, I recorded one testcase that contained a `click url`, then give the username and password and clicked the button to navigate to next page.
In the render page, if I click any link the error is shown as `Element link=linkname not found`.
Why does this error occur?

Answer (score 0):

Page is fully loaded when that command is executing?
If not just put `waitForPageToLoad` or `pause` command.

```
waitForPageToLoad | timeout
```

Or

```
pause  | 5000
```

Also you can use command `clickAndWait` for button after entering username and password

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways via which you can handle such issues. The issues can be of rendering as username and password click is fine as you will rest on same page when you enter values in these test boxes.

- But as soon as you click on submit button then application has to load a new page with the credentials you have just added.
- So this requires some time in terms selenium. What you can do is you can put some waits just after this action. So far selenium provides two types of waits Explicit and Implicit waits.
- And you can try thread.sleep() , its a java type of method which is also a kind of wait. But implicit and explicit waits are highly recommended in Selenium coding.

> You can refer to this blog for more knowledge on waits (http://khyatisehgal.wordpress.com/2013/05/09/how-to-handle-timeouts-implicit-and-explicit-waits-in-selenium/)

Khyati Sehgal